# Getting 404 Error While fetching MetaData of BIM360 Model using Forge SDK API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

i am trying to get Model Strucuture data of BIM360 Model That we store, for that i'm using metadata api passing threelegged Token, model urn, model guid, but getting 404 (Not Found Error). i tried for get model that we store in our bucket that we are getting from this api, but that model we stored in BIM360 Accounts for that API is giving Error of NOT Found,
i have passed all scope, backet:read, data:Read etc. couldn't getting result.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the HTTP request you're trying to send to the Model Derivative service? What exactly is the URN, the request headers, etc?

Comment: I'm using derivativeApi from forgeSDK, and as listParam pass  Pair param = new Pair("forceget", "true");
derivativesApi.getModelviewMetadata(urn, guid, null, listParam, oAuth2TwoLegged, twoLeggedCredentials);

Comment: And the `urn` and `guid` parameters, what do they look like and where did you get them from?

Comment: urn is dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwZW1lYTpmcy5maWxlOnZmLkFfenZuTlcyUjJpUzRDU2dQYnRxQkE_dmVyc2lvbj0x that we have stored in our db and for guid using this api derivativesApi.getMetadata(urn,.....) for getting guid of model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to guess what's wrong with the limited information but generally, the `404 Not Found` error would indicate that something in the URL (of the request made by the `derivativesApi.getModelviewMetadata` method call) is missing or wrong.

I'd suggest to look at the following:

- Could you take the URN, GUID, and access token, and make the request to the [GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET) endpoint directly using some  3rd party client application such as [curl](https://curl.se) or [postman](https://www.postman.com)?

  - If this returns 404, there might be some issue with the actual URN and/or GUID
  - If this works, there might be some issue in your code
- What Forge SDK exactly are you using, and for what language? Is it one of the official SDKs, or is it a 3rd party one?
- Are you sure you're passing in the right parameters to the `derivativesApi.getModelviewMetadata` method call?